# MYSQL Find similar strings that differs only for a hypen or extra space

Tags: mysql

I'd like to clean up my db of products because I noticed I have labels
like `Model X100` and `Model X-100` or `Model X 100`
The entries were user generated content so i didn't have much control in the old days.

I wonder if there is a way to SELECT in MYSQL those rows that are 99% similar but for an hypen or extra space

Comment: im not talking about that. how can I FIND THEM ALL not just one by one

Comment: `SELECT MAX(productName) FROM table GROUP BY REPLACE(REPLACE(productName, ' ', ''), '-', '')`